How do I speak the Firefox Remote Debugging protocol?
I am trying to learn how to use the Firefox Remote Debugging Protocol, but the wire protocol seems to be poorly documented, and I cannot appear to get the node example to run.
This is my first attempt, using nc to give a command based on the documentation:
# Terminal 1
firefox --start-debugger-server

# Terminal 2
nc 127.0.0.1 6000
# Output:
# 226:{"from":"root","applicationType":"browser","testConnectionPrefix":"server1.conn1.","traits":{"networkMonitor":true,"resources":{"extensions-backgroundscript-status":true}  ,"workerConsoleApiMessagesDispatchedToMainThread":true}}
# Input:
{ "to":"root", "type":"listTabs" }
# Output: No response.

This is my second attempt, using the client API example. Firefox is started the same way as above. I have created a file called Play.js with the contents copied verbatim from the example.
const { DevToolsServer } = require("devtools/server/devtools-server");
const { DevToolsClient } = require("devtools/client/devtools-client");

function start() {
  // Start the server.
  DevToolsServer.init();
  DevToolsServer.registerAllActors();

  // Listen to an nsIPipe
  let transport = DevToolsServer.connectPipe();

  // Start the client.
  client = new DevToolsClient(transport);

  client.connect((type, traits) => {
    // Now the client is connected to the server.
    debugTab();
  });
}


Then I executed it after installing devtools.
npm install devtools
node Play.js

I got the following error:
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'devtools/server/devtools-server'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/hq6/Code/FirefoxDebuggerPlay/Play.js:1:28)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)

What is the correct way to speak to Firefox over the remote debugging interface?
My goal is to learn the wire protocol so I can implement my own client in a language I am more familiar with.
However, I am also interested in answers that describe how to get the node client to work, since I can reverse engineer the protocol using the client if necessary.
I am not familiar with Node, so it is quite possible I am making a very simple mistake in trying to run the node client, or there is an obvious change that needs to be made that I am not aware of.

I figured out the protocol by reading the source code for the VSCode Extension.
It appears to be length-prefixed JSON messages, so sending the following via netcat works:
34:{ "to":"root", "type":"listTabs" }

However, this only works if I type it immediately after seeing the input, without an extra newline, because the protocol does not discard unexpected whitespace. Thus, in the terminal, the text looks like this:
226:{"from":"root","applicationType":"browser","testConnectionPrefix":"server1.conn2.","traits":{"networkMonitor":true,"resources":{"extensions-backgroundscript-status":true},"workerConsoleApiMessagesDispatchedToMainThread":true}}34:{ "to":"root", "type":"listTabs" }250:{"tabs":[{"actor":"server1.conn2.tabDescriptor1","browserId":2,"browsingContextID":3,"isZombieTab":false,"outerWindowID":6,"selected":true,"title":"New Tab","traits":{"watcher":true,"supportsReloadDescriptor":true},"url":"about:home"}],"from":"root"}

Furthermore, in order to send more than one message, I had to ensure that I did not add newlines after my first message either, which meant that I could not add a newline to force nc to send the bytes, and instead used Control-D to trigger an EOF.
